# Error 69 87 when do APDU verify instruction with biometric

Tags: java, iso, apdu, iso-19794

I'm doing a fingerprint verification process with a Chilean ID card.
It compliant with:
ICAO 9303 Part 3, Volume 2
• ICAO Technical Report LDS 1.7
• IAS ECC v1.0.1 specification
• ISO 14443, Type B
• ISO 7810
• ISO 7816-15
• ISO 19794-2
• ISO 19794-5
• Java Card 2.2.2
• Global Platform 2.1.1

It have Match On Card fingerprint verification.

It use iso 19794-2:2005 smart card.
I convert minutiae from ANSI 378 TO iso 19794-2:2005 smart card.
I did all process of security, challenger, mutual authentication, etc.
But when i send a encrypt APDU with INS 21 ( verify) I have this return message:
69 87 : Expected secure messaging (SM) object missing. I don't know what mean because when we sent unencrypted message it return 69 88, and we check that enc key, mac , etc are ok.
Anyone can help to discovery what mean?
we did try with different APDU ( with code 20,21, with tag 81 and 95, etc)
This is the last APU that we are using:

00210000BE7F2EBB81B4600b5c1f33800b082e334150087240411109720d991130c00d032e30412a033b40411b0c3b12a11b4140120f2e4141220f314041101031178110184017022e18413902520041111752229c112a8022082e2a4160082e40410e202e2ea10e3c402e0e173c205b0e264020062226304306144030052e144140055b00411a255b359c1a3d8035082e3d414f087140410f2c713f9a0f44c03f041744207304494020082d49405f084b80400b174b21420b04402104329503080910

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually error SW=6987 means that your secure channel protocol is not implemented correctly. For example, secured case 3 command should contain DO 87 (87-L-01-encrypted data) and DO 8E (8E-L-MAC). If you don't put DO 8E in the end of secured APDU data field, you'll have error "Expected secure messaging DOs missing".
By the way, Doc 9303 compliant cards don't store minutiae data. They store fingerprint image.

Comment: I use JMRTD for wap and unwrap secure message without issue. And the Chilean ID Card has Match On Card.  You know if i can obtain fingerprint image on doc  9303? i read specs and i don't found how i can obtain fingerprint image. Thanks!!

Comment: Doc 9303 (7th ed) part 9 tells that "the storage of the fingerprint image
is mandatory to permit global interoperability" and "The storage of an associated template is optional at the discretion of the issuing State." So, storage of minutiae data is possible, but not garanteed. If card stores fingerprint data, it can be found in data group 3 (EF ID=0103). Access to DG3 is protected with Extended Access Control - EAC (see Doc 9303 7th ed, part 11). Actually, EAC is specified in BSI TR-03110.